# Show modal without bootstrap.js (only jquery)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to emulate the function:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

without *Boostrap.js* but only with *jQuery*.

I tried:

```
$('body').addClass('modal-open');
$('#myModal').addClass('in');
$('#myModal').css('display', 'block');
$('#myModal').attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
```

but the page background is not fading out.

What did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

So solution was to add:

```
$('body').append('<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you want to make a modal dialog, you should write something like:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#myModal" ).dialog({
  modal: true
});
```

Comment: actually, i want to translate that functions in pure js, so i cant use dialog

Comment: Okay, could you edit your question to clarify this? I interpreted "with only jQuery" to mean that you could use jQuery.